# Wordress Newsletter disable redirection

Tags: wordpress, forms, popup, web-deployment, newsletter

We are trying to build a webpage where users can sign up to our newsletter. However, upon clicking the "subscribe" button, users by default go to a new separate page "Newsletter" where we say that the user is now subsribed.

In stead our goal is to print a short message below the form saying "you are now subscribed" or so. One possiblity that we can do, is to mimic the homepage, and the Newsletter to be the mimiced homepage, but seems really inefficient.

In stead a short message should suffice on the same page. But there is no option to disable the redirect and make a custom text field appears.

Suggestions?

Comment: Is there anything you already tried? Please tell us what you tried and what is not working as expected.Then we may be able to help you.

Comment: We tried to mimic the home page. But this is not satisfying option. We are using elementor, but there is no non-pro option.